# jQuery Object undefined when passed to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, parameters

I'm attempting to create an html element as a jQuery object, and then reference it later in a javaScript function.  After I pass it to the function as a parameter, however, the object becomes 'undefined.'

```
//globals
var handCanvasArray = new Array();
var canvasIdNum = 0;
```

Upon clicking a jQuery Mobile button, I create a new canvas element, store it in an array, and attempt to use it in a function:

```
//this code fires due to a button click
handCanvasArray[canvasIdNum] = $(document.createElement('canvas'));

//store the current canvasIdNum, then increment it for the next click
currCanvasID = canvasIdNum;
console.log("CurrCanvasID: " + currCanvasID);
canvasIdNum += 1;
Animate(handCanvasArray[currCanvasID]);
```

```
function Animate(pCanvasToAnimate) {
  console.log(pCanvasToAnimate);
  var canvasOffset = pCanvasToAnimate.offset();
}
```

The console prints two lines:
[object Object]
undefined

Program execution stops at attempting to assign the offset to a variable, due to the fact that pCanvasToAnimate is not considered to be an object.  Perhaps I'm declaring the new element incorrectly?  Or, perhaps I'm just mistaken/confused about how javascript handles object parameters.

Is there a better way to pass objects as parameters?

Edit: Editing for clarity.  Sorry folks!  Realized I left out some code regarding the index for the array, but the currCanvasID variable will equal canvasIdNum when Animate() is called.  I increment it so that the next time I click, that canvas will be stored in the next index (the overall flow for this could very well be improved at the moment ;) ).

Comment: You're using two different variables with the array, "canvasIdNum" and "currCanvasID", but only one of them is set to a value in the code you posted.

Comment: In your example, you're using two different variables (`canvasIdNum` and `currCanvasID`) as indexes to the `handCanvasArray`. Are they guaranteed to be the same value?

Comment: Just what I was about to say... what is `currCanvasID` set to?

Comment: Are you running this code in the console, or from a file? If you're running it in the console, I think that will explain the `undefined`, since it will be the return value of `console.log`. Try logging `pCanvasToAnimate.offset` to the console, and see if you get a function.

Comment: Oops, leaving out code!  I set currCanvasID equal to the canvasIdNum before Animating it, so these values are equal at time of Animate() being called.

@patrick, I logged pCanvasToAnimate.offset and the console returned two prints:  
'Offset function: function (a) ...'  
'TypeError: Result of expression 'pCanvasToAnimate' [undefined] is not an object.'    

So, perhaps I'm just creating the element incorrectly?  Thanks for this tip.

Comment: @Jared: *"...and the console returned two prints..."* Seems like your `Animate` function is getting called twice, the second time with no argument.

Comment: @Patrick: You were right.  For whatever reason, I figured the console was supposed to be returning two prints.  Upon further inspection, I had a separate Animate() call that had no parameters, which explains why the first console print was correctly showing an object while the second print was always undefined (d'oh!).  Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare your handCanvasArray as global, try to pass only a currCanvasID to your Animate() function and then reference the handCanvasArray directly from it.

K